# Intercept "Delete" from the Edit menu in Javascript

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I'm writing a Javascript application that utilises contentEditable. The browser's "Edit" menu contains a number of entries that change the contents of a contentEditable—I've found ways to intercept all of them apart from "Delete". So there's a `cut` event for the "Cut" menu item, a `paste` event for the "Paste" menu item, etc. What's the equivalent for the "Delete" menu item?

Answer (score 0):

So you mean you want to intercept when something is deleted or you want to launch a command to delete something? You could intercept a key event:

```
$(document).on('keydown', 'div[contenteditable="true"]', function(event){
    var parent = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));
    if (event.which == 46) {
        //if delete key is pushed do something
    } else if (event.which == 8) {
       //if backspace key is pushed do something
    }
});
```

Here is a list of all key codes in Javascript: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/
Here is a list of all the execCommand attributes available and browser compatibility:  http://help.dottoro.com/larpvnhw.php

If you want to delete the current selection you could use the document `range.deleteContents();` function which is compatible with most modern browser like this:

```js
 function RemoveSelection () {
            if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
                var selection = window.getSelection ();
                var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
                range.deleteContents();
                
            }
        }
```

```html
<div>
    Select some content on this page with the mouse!
</div>
<button onclick="RemoveSelection ();">Remove selected text</button>
```

You can also look into the `deleteFromDocument` method: http://help.dottoro.com/ljdslife.php

**Latest edit:** 
Okay, now that I understand your question better, I figured out you can use the on input event on your `contenteditable` to detect any changes to your contenteditable. Works both when you select some text and select delete from browser's menu, or when you use delete or backspace key. You basically compare text length from before and after.

There isn't really a default on delete event. Here is a list of all the events: http://help.dottoro.com/ljfvvdnm.php

```js
var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
var prevLength = editor.innerHTML.length;
function interceptDelete(evt) {
  var newLength = evt.target.innerHTML.length;
    if(newLength < prevLength) {
        alert('Deleted');
   }
  prevLength = newLength;
}
editor.addEventListener("input", interceptDelete, false);
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis mollis tellus. Nulla rhoncus venenatis malesuada. Donec mi neque, blandit nec efficitur sit amet, tincidunt vel arcu. Vivamus quis eros vitae nunc gravida hendrerit. Vivamus nibh neque, maximus at fringilla id, scelerisque vitae nulla. Aenean ut turpis ante. Sed gravida id magna nec sollicitudin. Sed quis justo eget erat elementum condimentum non sit amet mauris. Cras fringilla, justo fringilla interdum scelerisque, orci neque elementum erat, bibendum accumsan velit ipsum a ipsum. Ut sed tincidunt felis. Ut sed egestas mauris. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed dolor est, volutpat id suscipit at, faucibus et metus.

Donec non enim in nulla condimentum consequat. Praesent faucibus consectetur maximus. Maecenas quis leo lacinia, ornare enim at, iaculis magna. Donec faucibus nec est vitae lobortis. Nam fermentum tellus tempus, sollicitudin orci id, suscipit lacus. Pellentesque at tortor ultrices, cursus urna consequat, viverra sem. Vestibulum tempor enim nec est lobortis fermentum. Etiam eu accumsan ligula, eget placerat felis. Aliquam nec nunc eu ante dictum pretium. Morbi sed nulla quis libero commodo condimentum.</div>
```

And you could please appreciate the time I took for answering this with voting up or accepting my answer! Thanks!

Comment: No, I don't want to intercept the key event (I'm already doing that). I want to intercept the "Delete" entry of the "Edit" menu.

Comment: I have edited my post, I guess this should help get you started. Otherwise I don't really know what you're trying to achieve, maybe posting some code or being more specific would help.

Comment: maybe also look around for cross browser methods of detecting changes on your contentedit element but I guess that's where you can start from, by comparing previous text length with text length after change.

Answer (score 0):

The [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event is supported for `contenteditable` in Mozilla and WebKit browsers and fires when content is deleted via the browser menu. Sadly it isn't supported in IE yet.

http://jsfiddle.net/cfz1du4h/

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I believe that input is fired *after* the change has taken place and isn't cancellable? So, I can intercept (say) the "Paste" menu by handling the paste event, and stop the default behaviour by calling preventDefault. But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for the "Delete" menu item? And the input event doesn't help here because it's not cancellable.

Comment: @PaulButcher: That's all true. It wasn't clear from the question that cancelling the event before it's occurred was the requirement. I'm pretty certain there is no event specifically for deleting. You could undo the deletion using `document.execCommand('Undo', false, null)` but that's a hack and possibly not useful to you anyway.